# When Talking to a sensor IoT device from Bluemix Node-RED, what is the reasoning for connecting to IoT Foundation?

Tags: arduino, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, node-red

I see in the recipes for Bluemix that when I connect my Arduino Uno up with a sensor, that it's asking me to use the catalog boiler plate for IoT foundation (IoTF) rather than just the Node-Red boilerplate.  What is the reasoning for this? What more is IoTF providing? Is IoTF providing the MQTT broker?  Anything else? (note: I don't want to store any data, so don't want to pay for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two boiler plates is that the IoTF boiler plate comes with a example flow already deployed, and an instance of the IoTF service bound.

The IoTF service provides a shared MQTT broker and specifies topics to use so you do not clash with other users